# Move AWS Glacier vaults contents to another account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-glacier

I have recently realised that I have two separate Amazon accounts, created using different email addresses, one of them holding all my Kindle purchases, the other all Glacier uploads (120GB+). I'm looking for a way to "merge" them.

There is no way to move Kindle purchases, as far as I'm aware and there is no functionality to move the ownership of Glacier vault (as you can apparently do with S3 buckets)

Is there any way to move data to new vaults (or just move vaults) that wouldn't require reuploading everything from my computer (which would take a lot of time) or downloading data to an Amazon server and uploading from there (which would probably trigger a big cost for retrieval)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that Amazon doesn't support this operation. Unfortunately, it seems like you are stuck with deleting and Re-Creating it again.

[Disclosure : [Bucket Explorer]](http://www.bucketexplorer.com)